# What are good Powershell verbs for checking in/out files?

Tags: powershell, naming-conventions, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to stick to [the list of approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-5.1) for my Cmdlets. I currently have a cmdlet to check out a file from our version control system and I'm writing one to check a file back in as well.

I'm not sure which verbs really fit though for my naming. For the check-out I was using "Lock", but in addition to checking a file back in, I could also undo my check out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not having written any powershell cmdlets, what is wrong with obvious verb name "Checkin", "Checkout" and "UndoCheckout"?

Comment: @PeterM Powershell will give an annoying warning for cmdlets that don't use one of the standard verbs. The purpose of that set of approved verbs is to make cmdlets easily discoverable, like `Get-Command "Update-*"` (see link)

Comment: @marsze it sounds like a bad reason, when anyone would want to search everything they can update?

Comment: @appleapple I admit, that was probably a bad example, but consider this: For every resource (e.g. "Item", "CimInstance", etc.) you know **with certainty** what the verbs for the common actions (if available) will be, e.g. `Get-Item` / `Get-CimInstance`, `New-Item` /  `New-CimInstance`, `Remove-Item` / `Remove-CimInstance` etc (vs alternative possible names like Create-Item, Make-Item, Delete-Item etc. which would be confusing). So this makes everything more organized and thus easier to use.

Comment: I was thinking of this the other day.  There should be a tag just for 'Powershell-Naming' where we can go and submit our idea for a function and get help with naming.  Sometimes I find choosing an approved verb for my function an impossible task...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sticking to the "Accepted Verbs", I used Submit, Update, and Request for my TFS Module.

Also, you can add aliases called checkin, checkout, etc and you will not get a prompt saying your module has non-standard verbs when users import it.